# Display x-axis values on horizontal matplotlib histogram

Tags: matplotlib

I'd like to use matplotlib to display a horizontal histogram similar to the one below:

[image]

The code below works fine for vertical histograms:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Male'] * 10 + ['Female'] * 5})
plt.hist(df['A'])
plt.show()
```

[image]

The `orientation='horizontal'` parameter makes the bars horizontal, but clobbers the horizontal scale.

```py
plt.hist(df['A'],orientation='horizontal')
```

[image]

The following works, but feels like a lot of work.  Is there a better way?

```py
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_xticks([0,5,10])
ax.set_xticklabels([0,5,10])
ax.set_yticks([0,1])
ax.set_yticklabels(['Male','Female'])
df['A'].hist(ax=ax,orientation='horizontal')
fig.tight_layout()  # Improves appearance a bit.
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`plt.hist(df['A'])` only works by coincidence. I would recommend not to use `plt.hist` for non-numeric or categorical plots - it's not meant to be used for that.

Also, it's often a good idea to separate data aggregation from visualization. So, using pandas plotting,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Male'] * 10 + ['Female'] * 5})
df["A"].value_counts().plot.barh()
plt.show()
```

Or using matplotlib plotting,

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['Male'] * 10 + ['Female'] * 5})
counts = df["A"].value_counts()
plt.barh(counts.index, counts)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Very helpful, especially the comment about separating aggregation from display.  Accepting this answer!